# Spring Data REST move file rest-messages.properties to database

Tags: spring-boot-2

what needs to be added to spring boot 2, so that the value would first be checked in the database and if not found then searched in the file rest-messages.properties?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using JPA to fetch these values from Database table . If the result is not empty you can return value based on present in table. If its empty you can try to return from properties file.

Comment: no problem to use jpa. where is this bean in which i can write checks and substitutions ?